# how to make pandas isin output dataframe into json or list format

Tags: python, json, pandas, list, dataframe

here i have 2 dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': page})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col2': values})
result = df1[df1['col1'].isin(df2['col2'])]['col1'].value_counts()
```

and output is

```
variable_1    11
variable_2     4
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

i just want to print this without `Name: col1, dtype: int64` any kind of solution
i just tried for loop like

```
for i in result:
    print(i)
```

but it's showing only `11 & 4` ,,, not showing the `variable_1 & variable_2`
also tried `test1 = result.values.tolist()` and printed test1 but that is also getting values same like as above,,, `11 & 4`

any kind of solution friends.?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.items`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.items.html):

```
for a, b in result.items():
    print (a)
    print (b)
```